# Java loop at specific points

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have a java loop that I need to execute code on a specific point. I created an array to store the values at that I need the loop to execute at but am unsure how to todo this within the loop.

```
private int [] countdownValues = {22,42,62,82,102,122};
```

Pseudo code would look like

```
for(int i=0; i++)
if(i == countdownValue)
... else {}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're just asking how to check if an array *contains* a value?  Something like this?:

```
for (int i = 0; i < someValue; i++) {
    if(Arrays.binarySearch(countdownValues, i) > 0) {
        // perform a specific action
    } else {
        // perform the normal action
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this a little more. I'm struggling to implement it into my code. Thanks. Cannot find symbol Arrays?

Comment: @Razsberi: You might need to import `java.util.Arrays` if you don't already.  The class is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Thank you, fixed that problem. However using your code its not preforming a specific action each time i = a value within the array. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Razsberi: When you step through in a debugger, what is the value of `countdownValues` and the value of `i`?  If you execute just the conditional statement in the debugger on those values, what does it return?

Comment: Please check this and run for yourself. http://pastebin.com/9rs2vHpP .. the for loop isn't stoping at my values set in the array. :/

Comment: @Razsberi: Interesting.  I've no explanation of why that doesn't work.  But in any event, I've updated the answer with another approach.  (There are, after all, many ways of doing it.)  This is testing positively when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
// Iterate through the array
for(int i = 0; i < countdownValues.length; i++)
{
    if(i == countdownValue[specific point])
        // execute your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
int start = 0;

for (int end : countdownValues) {
    int i;
    for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
        // action(s) from then
    }

    // action(s) from else

    // start just after the end index next time
    start = end+1;
}
```

This assumes the values are all non-negative without duplicates and that they are inascending order.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `foreach` loop following way:

```
for (int value: countdownValues) {
    doStuff(value);
}
```

This way you won't be running unnecessary loops for values not in array.